# Eloquent: need to return also "distance" from this query (coordinates)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem but could not find anything useful. I need to get the "distance" variable that has been created by this query along with all the other data (user, userData, offers, and so on). I need to print the distance in 'km' within my view for every record I take.

Here's the code:

```
if(property_exists($params, "lat") && property_exists($params, "lng")) {
    if(null == $params->lat || null == $params->lng) {
        //don't use coordinates
    } else {
        $radius = $this->coordMaxRadius;
        $query->whereHas("userData", function($q) use ($params, $radius) {
            $q->selectRaw( \DB::raw("
            ROUND( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($params->lat) ) 
              * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
              * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($params->lng) ) 
              + sin( radians($params->lat) ) 
              * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance "));
            $q->having("distance", "<", $radius)->orderBy("distance");
        });
    }
} 
/***** later in the code *****/
$query->with("timeSlots.days", "timeSlots.time", "userData", 
             "university", "faculty", "user", 'userData.feedbacks');
```

Comment: After filtering it like this you could do a similar job inside a `foreach` loop that will calculate the **distance** and add it as a property where you need it `$query->userData->distance = $resultOfCalculation`.

Comment: @Mihailo I think i'll use this as a temporary solution until I could not find a purely relational solution

Comment: by your code, the query is not returning `distance` attribute? Instead of `$query->with(` try `$query->get()` and see if distance variable is there.

Comment: Hi @CerlinBoss, no the variable isn't there using the get, i thought it was there but indeed there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I am also handle the same problem few week before.I have solution but i dnt know exactly correct or not

```
$query->whereHas("userData", function($q) use ($params, $radius) {
$distance="ROUND( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($params->lat) ) 
          * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
          * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($params->lng) ) 
          + sin( radians($params->lat) ) 
          * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )";        
$q->selectRaw( \DB::raw($distance ." AS distance "));
        $q->having($distance, "<", $radius)->orderBy("distance");
    });
```

Comment: Yet nothing because that ->selectRaw for me is undefined, anyway it does not work